# Tic tac toe react state not updating

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and i am trying to build the tic tac toe game using the documentation, however using functional components on my own.

This is what I have done till now

app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Game />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Game.js

```
const styles = {
  width: "200 px",
  margin: "20px auto",
};

function Game() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(Array(9).fill(""));
  const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);
  const winner = calculateWinner(board);

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    const boardCopy = [...board];
    if (winner || boardCopy[i]) return;

    boardCopy[i] = xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
    setBoard(boardCopy);
    setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
  };

  function renderMoves() {
    return <button onClick={() => Array(9).fill(null)}> Start Game</button>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Board onClick={handleClick} squares={board} />
      <div style={styles}>
        <p>
          {winner ? "Winner " + winner : "Next player" + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O")}
          {renderMoves()}
        </p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Board.js

```
function Board({ onClick, squares }) {
  const style = {
    border: "4px solid darkblue",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    width: "250px",
    height: "250px",
    margin: "0 auto",
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplate: "repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr)",
  };

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {squares.map(
        (square, i) => (
          console.log(square),
          (
            <Square
              key={i}
              value={square}
              onClick={() => onClick("dummy value")}
            />
          )
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Button.js

```
function Square({ value, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button style={style} onClick={onClick}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

At this point in the code the game is functional and user should be able to play the game.

However, in my current code, when you click on Square nothing appears.

I checked in `Game.js`, the logic for `handleClick()` is same as the online documentation. These lines handle the logic for showing "X" and "O"

```
const boardCopy = [...board];
if (winner || boardCopy[i]) return;

boardCopy[i] = xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
setBoard(boardCopy);
setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
```

it creates a shallow copy of the original board and updates the original board state with the new one.

in Board.js, I put a `console.log(square)` to see what is being passed here, this shows `NULL`.

After the state is updated the console.log() show say X or O right?

What am I doing wrong here?

PS - I also one side question,

1)since I am new to this what is the difference of use between writing functions like below, both work perfectly so which should be used when?

```
function test({i}){
}
```

and

```
const test = (i) =>
{
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `onClick` with the string "dummy value" instead of the index of the clicked square?

Comment: `const test = (props) = > {}` you can use it as let x  = props.yourProp passed as `<Component youProp={yourProp}/>` or `const test = ({yourProp}) => {}` so you destructure it directly so you use it as let x = yourProp to get its value, if you dont use **this** keyword you can go with arrow function instead of traditional function, and you can't export default an arraw function, means you cannot import it as default  `import x from "./folder"` but like this `import {x} from "./folder"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are not doing nothing onClick, looks like onClick takes a parameter "i" but your passing "dummy value"

```
 <Square
       key={i}
       value={square}
       onClick={() => onClick("dummy value")}
  />
```

it should be something like

```
  function Board({ handleClick, squares }) {
  <Square
        key={i}
        index={i}
        value={square}
        handleClick={handleClick}
   />

  function Square({ value, index, handleClick}) {
     return (
        <button style={style} onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
           {value}
        </button>
     );
  }
```